# Assign mean marker color by hue groups for seaborn boxplot

Tags: python, pandas

I am aware a very similar question has been answered once before: [Assign color of mean markers while using seaborn hue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63038011/assign-color-of-mean-markers-while-using-seaborn-hue). Regardless, I cannot seem to be able to reproduce the solution. At least the 'ax-artists' is returning 0. The objective is to create a seaborn boxplot for data in two groups (hues). Unfortunately, there isn't data for every 'type' in 'loc', so I'd like to be able to color the mean markers by the hue colors. I imagine this can be done manually via calculating the means into a separate dataframe, but surely there is a better way of doing it than that? The image demonstrates the issue: the marker colors are incorrect and one of the markers is the default color. The legend is also unfortunately affected by the opacity setting, which should be avoided.
[image]
The reprex is below:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

tpar = "val"
data = {'type': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'c', 5: 'c', 6: 'c', 7: 'c', 8: 'd', 9: 'd', 10: 'e', 11: 'e', 12: 'e', 13: 'b', 14: 'b', 15: 'd', 16: 'e', 17: 'b', 18: 'd', 19: 'd', 20: 'e', 21: 'f', 22: 'f', 23: 'g', 24: 'h', 25: 'h', 26: 'h', 27: 'h', 28: 'h', 29: 'i', 30: 'j', 31: 'b', 32: 'b', 33: 'b', 34: 'b', 35: 'b', 36: 'b', 37: 'b', 38: 'b', 39: 'b', 40: 'b', 41: 'b', 42: 'c', 43: 'c', 44: 'c', 45: 'c', 46: 'c', 47: 'c', 48: 'c', 49: 'c', 50: 'c', 51: 'd', 52: 'd', 53: 'd', 54: 'd', 55: 'd', 56: 'd', 57: 'd', 58: 'd', 59: 'd', 60: 'e', 61: 'e', 62: 'e', 63: 'e', 64: 'e', 65: 'e', 66: 'e', 67: 'e', 68: 'e', 69: 'k', 70: 'k', 71: 'k', 72: 'k', 73: 'k', 74: 'k', 75: 'k'}, 'loc': {0: '1', 1: '1', 2: '1', 3: '1', 4: '1', 5: '1', 6: '1', 7: '1', 8: '1', 9: '1', 10: '1', 11: '1', 12: '1', 13: '1', 14: '1', 15: '1', 16: '1', 17: '1', 18: '1', 19: '1', 20: '1', 21: '2', 22: '2', 23: '2', 24: '2', 25: '2', 26: '2', 27: '2', 28: '2', 29: '2', 30: '2', 31: '2', 32: '2', 33: '2', 34: '2', 35: '2', 36: '2', 37: '2', 38: '2', 39: '2', 40: '2', 41: '2', 42: '2', 43: '2', 44: '2', 45: '2', 46: '2', 47: '2', 48: '2', 49: '2', 50: '2', 51: '2', 52: '2', 53: '2', 54: '2', 55: '2', 56: '2', 57: '2', 58: '2', 59: '2', 60: '2', 61: '2', 62: '2', 63: '2', 64: '2', 65: '2', 66: '2', 67: '2', 68: '2', 69: '2', 70: '2', 71: '2', 72: '2', 73: '2', 74: '2', 75: '2'}, 'val': {0: 9.707793424913127, 1: 13.386094727644041, 2: 23.79163880820678, 3: 10.39395928554849, 4: 16.10737178534521, 5: 14.280981644500402, 6: 13.37284106485653, 7: 9.438051071191, 8: 13.428417031257947, 9: 11.201719882794471, 10: 7.231770732496349, 11: 4.338483085841884, 12: 1.50907053154171, 13: 7.660083168740548, 14: 22.444633122805286, 15: 17.47145308755451, 16: 20.69718471318728, 17: 18.315282738981132, 18: 17.978380949794715, 19: 17.665480789484036, 20: 4.50274108225081, 21: 13.00879424293115, 22: 11.190356759760153, 23: 15.892212467377552, 24: 12.931549456351844, 25: 5.463525490936832, 26: 10.156762200578838, 27: 12.092758762869726, 28: 4.342703737075237, 29: 6.751842159450817, 30: 20.42046084888383, 31: 17.624071472791666, 32: 15.743860368917321, 33: 13.185896322157518, 34: 22.180832538032085, 35: 20.24978364632158, 36: 17.59687639466673, 37: 10.066630571468492, 38: 21.153824756899414, 39: 11.757339048404415, 40: 9.967497539236037, 41: 13.105560648792903, 42: 11.508803850577317, 43: 27.324971768461026, 44: 15.590194689475396, 45: 17.644975051594866, 46: 17.884712323792073, 47: 15.137560053438719, 48: 11.150836819567878, 49: 13.86822928951128, 50: 15.072225938867279, 51: 19.36268729077879, 52: 14.020243772704816, 53: 11.868300735988246, 54: 11.30447305533902, 55: 11.759812170322407, 56: 9.208486801410231, 57: 12.09441671041434, 58: 8.721831182283529, 59: 17.032203415542853, 60: 7.220149059582103, 61: 7.331398497538517, 62: 8.429772191688613, 63: 5.4195686050848, 64: 8.784087645946556, 65: 3.88845812696214, 66: 3.9065489464341416, 67: 3.8681574564882153, 68: 13.116477449330214, 69: 17.377320489000613, 70: 21.290156451172408, 71: 21.431382329030203, 72: 10.522720845810566, 73: 11.65610643463835, 74: 25.79359143984027, 75: 13.299067374572909}}
indata = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.boxplot(y= tpar, x= "type",hue='loc', data = indata, linewidth=0.5, palette= "bright",showmeans=True)
num_artists = len(ax.patches)
num_lines = len(ax.lines)
lines_per_artist = num_lines // num_artists
    
for i, artist in enumerate(ax.patches):
    col = artist.get_facecolor()
    artist.set_edgecolor('black')
    artist.set_alpha(0.1)
    for j in range(lines_per_artist):
        ax.lines[i * lines_per_artist + j].set_markerfacecolor(col)
        ax.lines[i * lines_per_artist + j].set_markeredgecolor('black')
        ax.lines[i * lines_per_artist + j].set_markeredgewidth(0.5)

ax.set_ylim(0, max(indata.get(tpar)))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, max(indata.get(tpar))+10,5))
plt.title('Test')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
ax.grid(b=True, which='major', color='black', linewidth=0.075)
ax.grid(b=True, which='minor', color='black', linewidth=0.075)
lgd = plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.12, 0.5), loc='center', borderaxespad=10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something intrinsically dangerous in the method that you used. You're looping over the artist without any knowledge of how they were drawn, only relying on their order. There are objects in `ax.patches` other than those in which you are interested (#0 and #2 are the legend patches).

You could try to filter on the type of artist, but this doesn't enable you to generalize if your plot contains other objects.

IMO, the cleanest approach is to plot the means yourself:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.boxplot(y= tpar, x= "type", hue='loc', data = indata, linewidth=0.5, palette= "bright")

# compute the means
means = indata.pivot_table(index='type', columns='loc', values='val')

# rework as Series, adding a shift around the left/right of your X ticks
s = means.stack()
shift = 0.2
x = (pd.factorize(s.index.get_level_values(0))[0]
    +s.index.get_level_values(1).map({'1': -shift, '2': shift})
    )
# compute the colors
color = s.index.get_level_values(1).map(dict(zip(['1', '2'], sns.color_palette('bright')))).tolist()

# plot the markers
ax.scatter(x, s, marker='^', c=color, zorder=3, edgecolor='k')
```

Output:

[image]